# simple Postgres UDF with case statement not working

Tags: postgresql, case, user-defined-functions

when I run the following code:

```
create or replace function roundfind(dates date) returns varchar as $$



begin 

select
case 
    when dates between '2020-06-08' and '2020-11-14' and dates is not null then return 'Round 1'
    when dates between '2020-11-15' and '2021-02-17' and dates is not null then return 'Round 2'
    when dates between '2021-02-18' and '2021-04-28' and dates is not null then return 'Round 3'
    when dates between '2021-04-29' and '2021-07-16' and dates is not null then return 'Round 4'
    when dates between '2021-07-16' and '2021-10-03' and dates is not null then return 'Round 5'
    when dates between '2021-10-04' and '2021-11-30' and dates is not null then return 'Round 6'
    when dates between '2021-12-01' and '2022-02-01' and dates is not null then return 'Round 7'
    when dates between '2021-02-02' and '2022-03-28' and dates is not null then return 'Round 8'
    when dates >= '2022-03-29' and dates is not null then return 'Round 9'
end 

end; $$

language PLPGSQL;


postgres.roundfind(date(19-5-2007)) -- function call
```

there is always some error, the most recent being:
"language is not defined". Even though I have defined it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use PL/pgSQL, you need to use `RETURN QUERY SELECT ...`

But you don't need PL/pgSQL to encapsulate a simple query, use `language sql` and get rid of the `begin ... end`

Also the `then return` should be `then`

```
create or replace function roundfind(dates date) returns varchar 
as $$
select
case 
    when dates between '2020-06-08' and '2020-11-14' and dates is not null then 'Round 1'
    when dates between '2020-11-15' and '2021-02-17' and dates is not null then 'Round 2'
    when dates between '2021-02-18' and '2021-04-28' and dates is not null then 'Round 3'
    when dates between '2021-04-29' and '2021-07-16' and dates is not null then 'Round 4'
    when dates between '2021-07-16' and '2021-10-03' and dates is not null then 'Round 5'
    when dates between '2021-10-04' and '2021-11-30' and dates is not null then 'Round 6'
    when dates between '2021-12-01' and '2022-02-01' and dates is not null then 'Round 7'
    when dates between '2021-02-02' and '2022-03-28' and dates is not null then 'Round 8'
    when dates >= '2022-03-29' and dates is not null then 'Round 9'
end;
$$
language sql;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=119131dc30e0f306ae47681e06e1aed8)

Note that the `and dates is not null` conditions in your CASE *expression* are redundant as `between` will only return `true` if the value is not null.

Comment: thanks but it gives an error "SQL Error [25P02]: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

Comment: @Ray92: you also need to remove the `return` after `then` - sorry didn't see that.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the function. You have made some (other) error but have not yet rolled back your transaction.